# Pillow upload path in pythonanewhere?

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, pythonanywhere

I'm using pythonanywhere.com and would like to attach images for my posts. When installed my model, I have a folder path for downloads like this

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="/static/uploads/",
```

but when I attach the photo I receive a message

> The joined path (/static/uploads/1.jpg) is located outside of the base path component (/home/farmville)

if I specify the full path

```
/home/username/project/static/uploads/
```

it's working, but in the template file this path does not work, the image is not :(

How can it can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

The two paths are different things, so using the same path doesn't make sense. The upload_to path is a path to a directory on the server where the image should be uploaded. The path in the template is probably a URL path (it's hard to tell without the actual template) and so it needs to point to where you're serving the uploads from.